# PHP random string generator

Tags: php, string, random

I'm trying to create a randomized string in PHP, and I get absolutely no output with this:

```
<?php
    function RandomString()
    {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randstring = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $randstring = $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
        }
        return $randstring;
    }

    RandomString();
    echo $randstring;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My one line solution for generate short string is substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);  good luck ...

Comment: @tasmaniski.. Your solution is ok.. But its less randomized! In your example the number of random strings that can be generated is limited by the size of integer. ( 2^32 ) at the max.. In case of the other solution, you can generate ( 62^8 ).. In case, I want larger strings, then number of distinct strings remain at max 2^32, but in the other solution it increases to ( 62^n )..

Comment: @tasmaniski: `printf("%08x", rand());` :)

Comment: You forgot to add each new generated character to the string. You're just overwriting it as it is. Should be $randstring .= $characters..

Comment: ^ this is the short and direct answer

Comment: @CaptainLightning Can you please swap out the accepted answer for one of the more secure ones? :)

Comment: wondering why this question have 384 upvotes.

Comment: calling function and printing another variable,
Do like this :
function RandomString()
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randstring  = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $randstring .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
 return $randstring;
}
echo RandomString();

Comment: `strlen($characters)` => `strlen($characters) - 1` - string length starts with 1

Comment: @tasmaniski, it should be `mt_rand()` instead of `rand()`.

Comment: Simple command: `php -r "echo sha1(rand());"`

Comment: Isn't 66 answers enough for this relatively simple question?

Comment: Keep in mind that, existentially speaking, there is no such thing as a random number.  God does not throw dice.  I am not suggesting we not use the word "random".  Only that when we do say "random, it is with the caveat that we understand there is no such thing as a random number, and that we are in fact referring to the "illusion" of randomness.

Comment: yet another solution `echo random_bytes(len)`[random_bytes](https://www.php.net/random_bytes)

Answer (score 1667, accepted):

To answer this question specifically, two problems:

1. `$randstring` is not in scope when you echo it.
2. The characters are not getting concatenated together in the loop.

Here's a code snippet with the corrections:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Output the random string with the call below:

```
// Echo the random string.
// Optionally, you can give it a desired string length.
echo generateRandomString();
```

> **Please note that previous version of this answer used `rand()` instead of `random_int()` and therefore generated predictable random strings. So it was changed to be more secure, following advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31107425/2373138).**

Comment: Your update is weird, this is a random generation but no char can be used more than once.

Comment: Why wasting that extra variable, `$i`? Just do `for ($randomString = ''; strlen($STR) < 50;) $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];` instead of your loop, or simplified, `for ($STR = ''; strlen($STR) < 50;) $STR .= $CHR[rand(0, strlen($CHR) - 1)];`

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia, It's better "wasting" an extra variable as of calling an method in the compare condition of an loop.

Comment: All that work, why not just something like `substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 10);`?

Comment: @SpYk3HH that's spot on, no duplicates at all using this.  Brain child!

Comment: Thanks for the code, but please change `rand()` to `mt_rand()`. I used your method and experienced a *ton* of collisions with names.

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker wouldn't you *want* duplicates in a random string?  If no character can be duplicated, you (significantly!) reduce the entropy in the generated string.

Comment: @RonLugge, I think you've misunderstood, I'm referring to the `MD5(microtime())` comment by @SpYk3HH.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia do you have any idea how horrifically inefficient that is? You are checking the length of a string twice per iteration! The strlen inside the loop should be cached in a variable before entering the loop as well.

Comment: @SpYk3HH That will not have uppercase letters.

Comment: @PavelBariev I suppose, if you must have some capitals, you could change it like so: implode('', array_map(function($i) { return rand(1, 10)%2 == 0 ? strtoupper($i) : $i; }, str_split(substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 10)))); [Blog](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2014/06/i-know-its-been-quite-while-and-i-need.html)

Comment: This is not a good solution. The strings this generates will be predictable. :(

Comment: Why does this cause the string length to change with random characters:
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]:";<>?,./';

Comment: So, if you don't want to offend people you should likely remove all of the vowels.  That way you will not be randomly creating bad words.

Comment: For pseudo random strings of length greater than 32 characters: `substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat(MD5(microtime()), ceil($len/32))), 0, $len)`

Comment: I am creating an online quiz that needs to generate random string to give a temporary id to multiple choices. does the predictability of this answer allow test participants to cheat?

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. It works for my use case as well. However, this solution produces errors with special characters like ä, ö, and ü.

To solve this, we need to take multibyte strings into account (default encoding with UTF-8 assumed): replace `$charactersLength = strlen($characters);` with `$charactersLength = mb_strlen($characters)`, and within the `for` loop add a variable `$charPos = random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1);`. Then replace `$randomString .= $characters[random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1)];` with `$randomString .= mb_substr($characters, $charPos, 1);`.

Answer (score 435):

> Note: `str_shuffle()` internally uses [`rand()`](https://secure.php.net/rand), which is unsuitable for cryptography purposes (e.g. generating random passwords). You want a [secure random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31107425/2224584) instead. It also doesn't allow characters to repeat.

## One more way.

**UPDATED** *(now this generates any length of string):*

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}

echo  generateRandomString();  // OR: generateRandomString(24)
```

That's it. :)

Comment: +1 for the shortest answer :). But not the best answer for every use-case. This code will output strings where each character won't appear more than once (thus making it weaker for brute force attacks) and won't output anything longer than 62 characters.

Comment: Do not do this, it is extremely weak. The longer you make your random string, the weaker it will be.

Comment: Weak it may be, but it's quick and easy. Depending on the use-case, this is fine -- I've used it because I didn't need security or strength; just a quick-fire shuffle. I'm writing a unit test, and this gives me a suitably random input to test with.

Comment: It could be even shorter if you use `range()`.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert , simply not true as shown in Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+62!+%2F+%2862+-+x%29!+from+55+to+62# (where x is the length of the password). It shows how 62 characters is as secure as 61, but for any other value from 0 to 61, the number of possibilities just grows.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia the reason it is not secure is because it never uses the same character twice. That makes it a _terrible_ password generator. Please everyone stop up voting this, it is totally insecure must never be used. As the password gets longer, the number of characters you must test in a brute force gets shorter because you do not bother testing any previously used character.

Comment: I agree that the rate of growth of the security decreases (added combinations per each added character), but the global security is still increased (total possible combinations), as you can see in the link I posted. That equation I wrote takes into account that it never uses a character twice and still supports my words... Do you think the equation is wrong or have any mathematical argument besides your word? Note: if the range of characters (0-9a-zA-Z) was much smaller, like (0-6), I'd agree that it'd be different, but that's not the case.

Comment: @francisco, your maths is spot on, but what's important is that if you allow characters to be repeated, and we're taking a 61 character password (since the 62nd adds nothing when you're just shuffling), then comparing 62^61 (allowing repeats) with 62! (shuffling) shows that allowing repeats gives you a password with 1.5*10^25 more combinations. That's a massive difference in security. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=61%5E62%2F62%21

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia: I support your comments about avoiding using this for random passwords. However, I disagree that this answer should not be plus-one'd. I have plus-one'd this option for since it is an effective one-line solution for generating random strings (the original topic of this question).

Comment: One can use str_repeat() to allow the same character multiple times: return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("characters", $length)), 0, $length); (But the original oneliner is really sufficient for any PRACTICAL use even without repeating characters.)

Comment: What if i'm need exclude numbers? I need only letters

Comment: A handy and elegant way to generate a random string. I am not using it for security purposes, so this gets my +1

Comment: **Answer updated.** Now it generates string with unlimited length.

Comment: I like this, simply because no one asked for a password secure random string, that is something that is insecure by itself so should not be done either way.

Comment: There was no mention of cryptography purposes in the question

Comment: Note: OP never mentioned the context in which the string would be used. They simply asked for assistance in addressing an issue with generating a simple random string, so the question of security and efficiency for cryptographic purposes might be irrelevant to the OP's needs.

Comment: for more security you can use this change: return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', $length)), 1, $length);

Comment: I searched for this for a bulk file renaming with no security needed whatsoever. This solution simply works.

Comment: @Lakitu The OP should indeed clarify his use case, as it appears from the OP's question the OP is clearly doing something that requires cryptographic strength. If, however, the OP is selecting random playing cards for Black Jack, Poker, etc, then "stronger cryptographic randomness" could potentially result in less clustering (until the back of the deck), which would translate to "weaker randomness" for a deck of cards, etc, because the game player can then predict minimal clustering and adjust his strategy. In the OP's case, however, this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: You can instantly make this secure by duplicating the input string two, three, or four times which makes it possible to repeat characters. For example, if your character pool is "Abc", use "AbcAbcAbc" instead.

Answer (score 433):

There are a lot of answers to this question, but none of them leverage a [Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/72902772336/how-not-to-csprng) (CSPRNG).

The simple, secure, and correct answer is to use [RandomLib](https://github.com/paragonie/RandomLib) and don't reinvent the wheel.

For those of you who insist on inventing your own solution, PHP 7.0.0 will provide [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int) for this purpose; if you're still on PHP 5.x, we wrote a [PHP 5 polyfill for `random_int()`](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) so you can use the new API even before you upgrade to PHP 7.

[Safely generating random integers in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php) isn't a trivial task. You should always check with [your resident StackExchange cryptography experts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) before you deploy a home-grown algorithm in production.

With a secure integer generator in place, generating a random string with a CSPRNG is a walk in the park.

#### Creating a Secure, Random String

```
/**
 * Generate a random string, using a cryptographically secure 
 * pseudorandom number generator (random_int)
 *
 * This function uses type hints now (PHP 7+ only), but it was originally
 * written for PHP 5 as well.
 * 
 * For PHP 7, random_int is a PHP core function
 * For PHP 5.x, depends on https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat
 * 
 * @param int $length      How many characters do we want?
 * @param string $keyspace A string of all possible characters
 *                         to select from
 * @return string
 */
function random_str(
    int $length = 64,
    string $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
): string {
    if ($length < 1) {
        throw new \RangeException("Length must be a positive integer");
    }
    $pieces = [];
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $pieces []= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
    }
    return implode('', $pieces);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
$a = random_str(32);
$b = random_str(8, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
$c = random_str();
```

**Demo**: https://3v4l.org/IMJGF (Ignore the PHP 5 failures; it needs random_compat)

Comment: At the beginning of the function add `$keyspace = str_shuffle($keyspace );` for more security

Comment: What do you mean by "for more security"? We're already using a secure random number generator.

Comment: Notice: The "RandomLib" is no more supported, from I see. It has last commit from about 11 months (from now) and problems with PHP 7.1: https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib/issues/55
Someone from this issue suggested to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Would you mind posting an updated version which is fixed with what you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: The question was not about cryptography

Comment: @JGEstiot Creating securely random strings requires cryptographically secure randomness. Someone searching "how to generate random strings in PHP" is better served by a secure answer than an insecure answer.

Comment: @ Scott Arciszewski  You do not need to create cryptographically random strings every time  you create random strings. The question was about creating randomized strings and this has nothing to do with security. You assumed that the string is going to be used in a security-sensitive context and you add a layer of complexity that deters from the core of the question.

Comment: Using `random_int()` instead of `rand()` or `mt_rand()` adds no complexity for the developer. At the same time, it gives them greater security.

People who come to StackOverflow looking for quick solutions might not know if the thing they're building needs to be secure or not. If we give them secure-by-default answers, they create a more secure Internet even if, from their perspective, it's totally accidental. Why you would oppose this goal is a mystery to me.

Comment: Due to this function accept 2nd parameter (`$keyspace`) and you are using string index (`$string[12]` - for example) which is not support multi-byte or unicode characters. ( see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr )
So, this would be good if it is able to check for ascii characters first using `if (strtolower(mb_detect_encoding($keyspace)) === 'ascii'`) otherwise it can random something like `'กขคงจฉช'` to `'���'`.

Comment: Don't use it on multibyte strings. Write your own if you want that.

Comment: I would suggest a few minor improvements, to harden this function further and prevent it's mis-use. As the author rightly says, why not make it as good as possible for the copy and pasters! Add type declarations for the arguments (for PHP 7+ use of course), "int" and "string" respectively and return casting, "string". A strong default length, 64? Then add an error for the length being less than 1, which would result in a blank string.

Comment: I am sure the OP knows this already, but it's worth mentioning: remove vowels to avoid generating some pretty fancy curse words, if you'll be sending this password in an email to your new customers / new registered users.

Comment: I really like your answer, but I question myself. Why do you use implode() at the end and not just append the new characters with a .= instead of adding them to an array? Is there a huge performance impact?

Comment: I wanted to echo @KevinGlier's question. Love this answer, but what's the purpose of constructing an array and them imploding it back into a string (which is basically already an array of characters anyway)? I assume there's good reason, I just don't understand it.

Comment: To answer my own question, even when generating 100,000 strings of various lengths, there is no performance impact that I could detect. You may as well change to a string if that feels more readable.

Comment: I was looking for an answer like yours. Thank you @scott-arciszewski!

Comment: Years later and your answer is still very useful. Thank you so much. It is exactly what I want, a simple and generalized solution.

Answer (score 224):

This creates a 20 character long hexadecimal string:

```
$string = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10)); // 20 chars
```

In PHP 7 ([random_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)):

```
$string = base64_encode(random_bytes(10)); // ~14 characters, includes /=+
// or
$string = substr(str_replace(['+', '/', '='], '', base64_encode(random_bytes(32))), 0, 32); // 32 characters, without /=+
// or
$string = bin2hex(random_bytes(10)); // 20 characters, only 0-9a-f
```

Comment: Please note that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` did not use a cryptographically strong algorithm until php 5.6. Related bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70014

Comment: Also note that the smallest string this can make is of length 2. If you pass a byte length of 1 or less to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` you will get nothing back. Also, note that when using `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length / 2))` since you are working with integers, it will automatically remove the modulo and will use the next lowest multiple of 2. So, `$length = 19` will produce a string of length 18.

Comment: Proposal to use it as file content that can be opened through `fgets($fp, 1024)` and every file editor that has problems with very long lines: `function string_rand($len, $split="\n") {
 return substr(chunk_split(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(ceil($len / 2))), 1023, $split), 0, $len);
}` Set `$split` to `null` if it should return a one-liner. By that you can use it for both cases.

Comment: I really like the random_bytes solution for PHP 7, but if you need the string to be a certain number of characters would something like this work? `$string = substr(base64_encode(random_bytes($size)), 0, $size);`

Comment: This is absolutely without a doubt the best solution. Takes up very little space and is super easy to understand.

Comment: Note that `base64_encode` uses the 62 alphanumeric characters plus `/` and `+`. Furthermore, `bin2hex` use only 16 alphanumeric characters, that may be not enough. So the better is to take a long random string, to base64 it, to remove `+` and  `/`, and to substr the result: 

`$string = substr(str_replace(['+', '/', '-', '='], '', base64_encode(random_bytes(32))), 0, 16); // "always" 16 chars.`

Comment: @Daniel-KM I agree. That's how I always use it. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Ha! What a nice surprise!: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/a69cfb1860c36f607d0822ee88d8a67da35fa5d8/src/PHPMailer.php#L2753

Answer (score 115):

@tasmaniski: your answer worked for me. I had the same problem, and I would suggest it for those who are ever looking for the same answer. Here it is from @tasmaniski:

```
<?php 
    $random = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 7);
    echo $random;
?>
```

Here is a [youtube video showing us how to create a random number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O1J_TdD0dI&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: if your string is based on only a random integer, why not just use the random integer? they haystack doesnt get any deeper by hashing it... and by cutting the hash of you actually deminish the little entropy you had to start with.

Comment: Keep in mind `md5` will result in a 30 character limit and always lowercase characters.

Comment: Additionally, rand() shouldn't be used for cryptography. If you're looking to generate a crypographically sound string, use [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).

Comment: `md5(rand())` only offers 2^32 possible values. This means after, on average, 2^16 random strings you will expect one to repeat.

Comment: Well..i would bet the OP is not talking about "securely random strings". This solution is compact, easy and pretty to remember, for the **right** use cases. And, if you need to take care of possible collisions, why not to prepend/append a timestamp to the random string? :)

Comment: A pseudo-random integer with a cycle of 2^16 or 2^32 fed into SHA-256 with a long secret salt creates an almost cryptographically secure value, even though there may only be 2^16 values possible. The reason is that without knowing the secret salt one cannot cycle through all 2^16 values. If there is no salt, then it is possible to cycle through all the integers in range 2^16 and try each value.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.51 (Unix) Server at t9155861.beget.tech Port 80

Answer (score 51):

Depending on your application (I wanted to generate passwords), you could use

```
$string = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(30));
```

Being base64, they may contain `=` or `-` as well as the requested characters. You could generate a longer string, then filter and trim it to remove those.

`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` seems to be the recommended way way to generate a proper random number in php. Why `rand` doesn't use `/dev/random` I don't know.

Comment: rand doesn't use /dev/urandom because that is only available in posix like environments and is not portable.

Comment: @MacroMan But `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` *is* portable.

Comment: If you want to strip out the extra base64 characters, try this: https://gist.github.com/zyphlar/7217f566fc83a9633959

Comment: This isn't wrong, but I would advise caution in how you discard the unwanted characters. See [this pull request on the PHP league's OAuth2 Server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/pull/273), for example.

Comment: This is one of the best answers. Pity it doesn't have more support. I would recommend editing your answer for better handling of unwanted characters though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the two characters you list are incorrect for most current base64 algorithms. Besides, base64 takes up more space than ordinary characters, which can be sanitized as desired. And if you have space to burn, use hexadecimal. It is always safe.

Comment: Replace rather than discard. I will let the reader sort out why this is preferable.

Answer (score 39):

**PHP 7+** Generate cryptographically secure random bytes using [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) function.

```
$bytes = random_bytes(16);
echo bin2hex($bytes);
```

Possible output

> da821217e61e33ed4b2dd96f8439056c

**PHP 5.3+** Generate pseudo-random bytes using [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function.

```
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
echo bin2hex($bytes);
```

Possible output

> e2d1254506fbb6cd842cd640333214ad

The **best use case** could be

```
function getRandomBytes($length = 16)
{
    if (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        $bytes = random_bytes($length / 2);
    } else {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length / 2);
    }
    return bin2hex($bytes);
}
echo getRandomBytes();
```

Possible output

> ba8cc342bdf91143

Comment: This will not generate a string with the given length

Comment: getRandomBytes() (all of them, really) only works for even lengths. Other than that, one of the better, less-scary answers here.

Comment: @DewiMorgan, I guess any hashing algo generates even length.

Comment: Well, it's more that bin2hex() specifically will inevitably return an even number of hex chars. Truncating the output by one char for odd-length cases shouldn't, *so far as I can tell*, affect the entropy... but I admit it'd add a few extra lines to the code that would be pointless for almost all use-cases.

Comment: So $odd=$length%2; $length+=$odd; at the beginning, and return substr(bin2hex($length), $odd); at the end would do the trick... but at the cost of considerable readability. Yours is cleaner and more maintainable, so I'd probably just add a comment about the "only even lengths" caveat if I were to use it, unless it truly mattered.

Comment: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes was slow on PHP < 5.3.4 Windows

Answer (score 29):

Here is a simple one-liner that generates a true random string without any script level looping or use of OpenSSL libraries.

```
echo substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', mt_rand(1,10))), 1, 10);
```

To break it down so the parameters are clear

```
// Character List to Pick from
$chrList = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

// Minimum/Maximum times to repeat character List to seed from
$chrRepeatMin = 1; // Minimum times to repeat the seed string
$chrRepeatMax = 10; // Maximum times to repeat the seed string

// Length of Random String returned
$chrRandomLength = 10;

// The ONE LINE random command with the above variables.
echo substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($chrList, mt_rand($chrRepeatMin,$chrRepeatMax))), 1, $chrRandomLength);
```

This method works by randomly repeating the character list, then shuffles the combined string, and returns the number of characters specified.

You can further randomize this, by randomizing the length of the returned string, replacing `$chrRandomLength` with `mt_rand(8, 15)` (for a random string between 8 and 15 characters).

Comment: sorry to say but when one character gots selected its probability of occuring again is not as high as the other characters still remaining in the pool. no true randomness here...

Comment: @TheSurrican - You would be incorrect in that statement.  All characters have an equal probability using this algorithm, and thus is truly random. This is ensured by repeating the chrList string $chrRepeatMax, and the magic really happens in str_shuffle which determines the randomness.

Comment: All chars would appear only once and it is very prone to bruteforce guess

Comment: @venimus Thats incorrect.  The char string is duplicated for as many characters as you want (see `$chrRepeatMax` and `$chrRepeatMin` ) -- so a 10 char string , could (unlikely, but possible), be "aaaaaaaaaa".

Comment: @SanuelJackson Sorry I miss-commented. I've put the comment on the wrong answer. You are right! I actually used your "trick", but didn't use mt_rand, because it is useless IMHO. It does not add to the entropy. Just used const with the max-length.

Comment: @venimus - The difference is speed :  "The mt_rand() function is a drop-in replacement for the older rand(). It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the » Mersenne Twister, which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides."

Comment: What I mean is that `str_shuffle` randomizes it anyway

Comment: This algorithm is clever, but it is based on mt_rand, which generates a deterministic sequence of numbers. The output can be decoded by obtaining or guessing the salt. A true random sequence cannot be decoded into something with less entropy, like a small integer, under any conditions. A good approximation to true randomness is achieved by some systems by generating real-world entropy through such means as measuring how long it takes a person to type or move a mouse. Note that using the system time is not truly random, either, since an attacker can sometimes intercept device timing signals.

Comment: str_shuffle is deterministic, not truly random.

Comment: Downvote reasons: 1) claims "a *true* random string" rather than "a *pseudo*random string" when mt_rand is not truly random; claims equal probability of character selection, which shows a misunderstanding of statistics. Once the first character is selected from the string, the probability of it's selection for the second is then 9/(10*n) while all other characters are 10/(10*n). This stuff matters: such errors are dangerous in a security context.

Answer (score 26):

A better way to implement this function is:

```
function RandomString($length) {
    $keys = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'));

    $key = "";
    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[mt_rand(0, count($keys) - 1)];
    }
    return $key;
}

echo RandomString(20);
```

`mt_rand` is more random according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php#105265) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php#112227) in PHP 7. The `rand` function is an alias of `mt_rand`.

Comment: Caution: `mt_rand` does not generate cryptographically secure values. For that you should use PHP7's `random_int` or `random_bytes`.

Answer (score 25):

```
function generateRandomString($length = 15)
{
    return substr(sha1(rand()), 0, $length);
}
```

Tada!

Comment: Keep in mind `sha1` will result in a 40 character limit and always lowercase characters.

Comment: sha1 strings are not random, certain characters will occur more frequently than others. It would be unwise to use this in cases where you genuinely want randomness like for passwords.

Comment: @KitSunde - yes, sha isn't random, rand() is random. And sha is perfectly fine for what is needed here. OP doesn't need crypto level of randomness.

Comment: @Davor `rant()` being random doesn't matter when sha isn't evenly distributed. If you randomly select from an uneven distribution you get the exact same uneven distribution. It's not "crypto level" randomness I'm highlighting, if that was the case you shouldn't be using `rand()` either. It takes minimal effort to pluck from an even distribution like in the accepted answer and it's as random as rand() is which is reasonably so.

Comment: @KitSunde - it makes literally no difference in the end. That's exactly the definition of overengineering and gold plating.

Comment: @Davor Well if you want to not overengineer you may as well do `function generateRandomString(){return "asdf"; /* Decided by fair dice roll */  }`. ;) The definition of over engineering isn't making a function 7 lines long so it does what it advertised it does and doesn't just surprisingly fail when being  asked for more than 40 characters. ;) There's also something called "the principle of least surprise". But shrug, good talk, I think I'm happy that you're happy, I have no need to discuss this further.

Comment: @KitSunde - except that one wouldn't do the job, and this one does, perfectly for what is needed, in one simple line of code.

Comment: Very neat. Maybe rename the function "generateRandomHexString" to make it clear the string only contains hex characters?

Answer (score 18):

`$randstring` in the function scope is not the same as the scope where you call it. You have to assign the return value to a variable.

```
$randstring = RandomString();
echo $randstring;
```

Or just directly echo the return value:

```
echo RandomString();
```

Also, in your function you have a little mistake. Within the for loop, you need to use `.=` so each character gets appended to the string. By using `=` you are overwriting it with each new character instead of appending.

```
$randstring .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's my simple one line solution to generate a use friendly random password, excluding the characters that lookalike such as "1" and "l", "O" and "0", "5" and "S", etc... this example generates 5 characters string but you can easily change it by modifyling the last variable:

```
$user_password = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXYZ2346789'),0,5);
```

It's obviously not the most secure solution as it has a limited amount of different characters and each can only be used once in the output, but a 5 character long string will still allow over 311 million combinations, and a 7 character long over 674 billion combinations, etc, so it's still an elegent, user-friendly, super light and easy to use method for non-critical uses.

Comment: This is perfect to create random ID strings to call later on jquery. IDK if its good practice but this helped me alot, without using a for like the accepted answer...

Comment: This method is somewhat "less random" than you might first expect, since there is no chance any character will be used more than once.

Comment: You're right @Deji, a five characters length string will "only" have 379 million possible combinations instead of 459 million.

Comment: It's actually just under 312 million permutations that your 5-char sub-strings can generate. I'm not sure how to calculate the latter to be honest.

Comment: @Deji how did you get to 312M? The songs pics the first from 54 characters, then from the remaining ones, etc, five times, that's 54*53*52*51*50 = 379.501.200 possible combinations.

Comment: @rAthus Oh, because I assumed you were just using both upper and lower case alphabetical characters (thus 52) more like what the OP was doing... but for some reason you're using a subset of alpha-numerics? Now I question the usage of such a random string generation at all, as generating something that's supposed to be secure in a way that's human readable are at odds, and using `str_shuffle` is probably not cryptographically secure.

Comment: @Deji OP is using numbers as well making his string 62 chars so that would be even MORE possible outcomes, why I chose to reduce as explained in my post, it is made to be user friendly by removing look alike characters so that a humain has no trouble reading it whatever font is used, and using only a one-line light function, this can be very useful when generating a random password for a user for example, or a strong discount code, or magic key to access simething, etc...

Answer (score 16):

First, you define the alphabet you want to use:

```
$alphanum = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$special  = '~!@#$%^&*(){}[],./?';
$alphabet = $alphanum . $special;
```

Then, use [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) to generate proper random data:

```
$len = 12; // length of password
$random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len);
```

Finally, you use this random data to create the password. Because each character in `$random` can be `chr(0)` until `chr(255)`, the code uses the remainder after division of its ordinal value with `$alphabet_length` to make sure only characters from the alphabet are picked (note that doing so biases the randomness):

```
$alphabet_length = strlen($alphabet);
$password = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    $password .= $alphabet[ord($random[$i]) % $alphabet_length];
}
```

Alternatively, and generally better, is to use [RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib) and [SecurityLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/SecurityLib):

```
use SecurityLib\Strength;

$factory = new RandomLib\Factory;
$generator = $factory->getGenerator(new Strength(Strength::MEDIUM));

$password = $generator->generateString(12, $alphabet);
```

Comment: The use of the modulo operator `%` will produce biased output. However, strong +1 for RandomLib. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, the new random_int() function is nice :D

Answer (score 15):

I've tested performance of most popular functions there, the time  which is needed to generate 1'000'000 strings of 32 symbols on my box is:

```
2.5 $s = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,32);
1.9 $s = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(24));
1.68 $s = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
0.63 $s = base64_encode(random_bytes(24));
0.62 $s = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
0.37 $s = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 32);
0.37 $s = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 32);
```

Please note it is not important how long it really was but which is slower and which one is faster so you can select according to your requirements including cryptography-readiness etc.

substr() around MD5 was added for sake of accuracy if you need string which is shorter than 32 symbols.

For sake of answer: the string was not concatenated but overwritten and result of the function was not stored.

Comment: I think, that best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

```
function gen_uid($l=5){
   return substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"), 10, $l);
}
echo gen_uid();
```

> Default Value[5]: WvPJz

```
echo gen_uid(30);
```

> Value[30]: cAiGgtf1lDpFWoVwjykNKXxv6SC4Q2

Answer (score 12):

One very quick way is to do something like:

```
substr(md5(rand()),0,10);
```

This will generate a random string with the length of 10 chars. Of course, some might say it's a bit more heavy on the computation side, but nowadays processors are optimized to run md5 or sha256 algorithm very quickly. And of course, if the `rand()` function returns the same value, the result will be the same, having a 1 / 32767 chance of being the same. If security's the issue, then just change `rand()` to `mt_rand()`

Answer (score 12):

## Short Methods..

Here are some shortest method to generate the random string

```
<?php
echo $my_rand_strng = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), -15); 

echo substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);

echo str_shuffle(MD5(microtime()));
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Helper function from Laravel 5 framework

```
/**
 * Generate a "random" alpha-numeric string.
 *
 * Should not be considered sufficient for cryptography, etc.
 *
 * @param  int  $length
 * @return string
 */
function str_random($length = 16)
{
    $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, $length)), 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: "Should not be considered sufficient for cryptography, etc." This should be strongly emphasized.

Answer (score 9):

Since php7, there is the random_bytes functions.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.random-bytes.php
So you can generate a random string like that

```php
<?php
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
var_dump(bin2hex($bytes));
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

from the yii2 framework

```
/**
 * Generates a random string of specified length.
 * The string generated matches [A-Za-z0-9_-]+ and is transparent to URL-encoding.
 *
 * @param int $length the length of the key in characters
 * @return string the generated random key
 */

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $bytes = random_bytes($length);
    return substr(strtr(base64_encode($bytes), '+/', '-_'), 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: good solution i made this in a different way using the same technique thank you mate

Comment: Works for what I needed to achieve, many thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
function rndStr($len = 64) {
     $randomData = file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, $len) . uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
     $str = substr(str_replace(array('/','=','+'),'', base64_encode($randomData)),0,$len);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: This is not portable; if you try to run this in any non-posix environment, it will cause a fatal error.

Answer (score 7):

This one was taken from [adminer sources](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/63f2a041ed70be3ceb234fba684d715555e7551a/adminer/include/functions.inc.php#L1107):

```
/** Get a random string
* @return string 32 hexadecimal characters
*/
function rand_string() {
    return md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}
```

[Adminer](https://github.com/vrana/adminer), database management tool written in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I am doing it to get a true unique random key:

```
$Length = 10;
$RandomString = substr(str_shuffle(md5(time())), 0, $Length);
echo $RandomString;
```

You can use time() since it is a Unix timestamp and is always unique compared to other random mentioned above. You can then generate the md5sum of that and take the desired length you need from the generated [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) string. In this case I am using 10 characters, and I could use a longer string if I would want to make it more unique.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Of course, `time()` is far from unique: it'll return the same value again and again until current second ends. What really provides some randomness here is `str_shuffle()`—the rest of the code only reduces the sample to pick chars from.

Comment: so what you are basically doing is shuffling around a 32 bit integer. not a lot of entropy here...

Comment: An attacker can guess the value returned by `time()` (it's only a timestamp), it's a weak source of randomness.

Comment: Please note, he also uses a str_shuffle. Even if an attacker guess the time, he cannot guess the result of the shuffle function. I think it is secure enough.

Answer (score 5):

Another one-liner, which generates a random string of 10 characters with letters and numbers. It will create an array with `range` (adjust the second parameter to set the size), loops over this array and assigns a random ASCII character (range 0-9 or a-z), then implodes the array to get a string.

```
$str = implode('', array_map(function () { return chr(rand(0, 1) ? rand(48, 57) : rand(97, 122)); }, range(0, 9)));
```

**Note: this only works in PHP 5.3 and later**

Comment: finally a truly random solution not some bloated hash of a 32 bit random integer or a shuffled string...

Comment: theres just one issue: numbers are as likely to occur as characters, which is not as random as i would love to have it. anyaway +1 for the best solution on this page. tweak that and its perfect.

Comment: tweak... like this? `rand(0, 57-48+122-97)<57-48?...:...` ? :)

Answer (score 5):

One liner.

It is fast for huge strings with some uniqueness.

```
function random_string($length){
    return substr(str_repeat(md5(rand()), ceil($length/32)), 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: `md5(rand())` is a horrendously insecure way to generate a random number.

Comment: a string with X length and some uniqueness is the intent. true randomness is not the intent.

Answer (score 5):

```
function randomString($length = 5) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(implode(array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9)))), 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * @param int $length
 * @param string $abc
 * @return string
 */
function generateRandomString($length = 10, $abc = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
{
    return substr(str_shuffle($abc), 0, $length);
}
```

Source from http://www.xeweb.net/2011/02/11/generate-a-random-string-a-z-0-9-in-php/

Answer (score 4):

The edited version of the function works fine, but there is just one issue I found: You used the wrong character to enclose $characters, so the ’ character is sometimes part of the random string that is generated.

To fix this, change:

```
$characters = ’0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ’;
```

to:

```
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

This way only the enclosed characters are used, and the ’ character will never be a part of the random string that is generated.

Answer (score 4):

```php
function generateRandomString($length = 10, $hasNumber = true, $hasLowercase = true, $hasUppercase = true): string
{
    $string = '';
    if ($hasNumber)
        $string .= '0123456789';
    if ($hasLowercase)
        $string .= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    if ($hasUppercase)
        $string .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x = $string, ceil($length / strlen($x)))), 1, $length);
}
```

and use:

```php
echo generateRandomString(32);
```

Answer (score 3):

I liked the last comment which used openssl_random_pseudo_bytes, but it wasn't a solution for me as I still had to remove the characters I didn't want, and I wasn't able to get a set length string.   Here is my solution...

```
function rndStr($len = 20) {
    $rnd='';
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
        do {
            $byte = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1);
            $asc = chr(base_convert(substr(bin2hex($byte),0,2),16,10));
        } while(!ctype_alnum($asc));
        $rnd .= $asc;
    }
    return $rnd;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
<?php
    function random($len){

        $char = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // ----------------------------------------------
        // Number of possible combinations
        // ----------------------------------------------
        $pos = strlen($char);
        $pos = pow($pos, $len);
        echo $pos.'<br>';
        // ----------------------------------------------

        $total = strlen($char)-1;
        $text = "";

        for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
            $text = $text.$char[rand(0, $total)];
        }
        return $text;
    }

    $string = random(15);
    echo $string;
?>
```

You can also use md5 on time but be careful.

You need to use `microtime()` and not `time()` function, because if multiple threads run within the same second, you need to get different string for all of them.

```
<?php

    $string = md5(microtime());
    echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//generateRandomString http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator
function randomString($length = 32, $string= "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ) {
    //$string can be:
    //0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    //0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    return substr(str_shuffle( $string), 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from php8.3 you can do this:

```
$rng = new Random\Randomizer();
$crockfordAlphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ';
$rng->getBytesFromString($crockfordAlphabet, 10); // "5YH837JSJT"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to generate a random string in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) is:

```
function RandomString($length) {
    $original_string = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A', 'Z'));
    $original_string = implode("", $original_string);
    return substr(str_shuffle($original_string), 0, $length);
}
echo RandomString(6);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is simple code:

```
echo implode("",array_map(create_function('$s','return substr($s,mt_rand(0,strlen($s)),1);'),array_fill(0,16,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")));
```

There is a simple guide:

- To change the *length of string*, please change the `16` to another value, only.
- To select from different characters, please change the character string.

Comment: Is this really superior to the other answers here?

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Parametrised one-liner using only **PHP native functions**, working since **PHP 5.1.0**

```
str_shuffle(implode('', (array_intersect_key(($map =  array_map('chr', array_merge(array_map('mt_rand', array_fill(0, $length = 25, 48), array_fill(0,$length,57)),array_map('mt_rand', array_fill(0, $length, 65), array_fill(0,$length,90)),array_map('mt_rand', array_fill(0, $length, 97), array_fill(0,$length,122))))), array_flip($keys = array_rand($map, $length))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner. You'll get at least one lower-case, one upper-case, one number, and one symbol. Uses `random_int` which is supposed to cyrptographically secure. I do not claim this to be secure, though. I am not a security expert.

To copy+Paste: (just change `$len` to your desired length.)

```php
$len=26;for ($chars = array('0123456789','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','!@#$%^&*()_+-='),$randomString="",$i=0;$i<$len;$i++)$randomString .= substr($chars[$i%4], random_int(0,strlen($chars[$i%4])), 1);
echo $randomString;
```

And a little more broken down:

```
for (
        $chars = array('0123456789','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','!@#$%^&*()_+-='),
        $randomString="",
        $i=0;
        $i<12;$i++)
        $randomString .= 
            substr($chars[$i%4], 
                random_int(0, strlen($chars[$i%4])), 1);
```

I use `$chars[$i%4]` in the loop to choose which set of characters to get a random from. It guarantees multiple characters from each set of chars in the array.

It could definitely be improved (randomizing how many of each char set there is), but it's good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution.

```
function genRandomString($length = 10)
{
    if($length < 1)
        $length = 1;
    return substr(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2))), 0, $length);
}
```

PS. I am using PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

```
function randomName($length = 8) {
  $values = array_merge(range(65, 90), range(97, 122), range(48, 57));
  $max = count($values) - 1;
  $str = chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
  for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $str .= chr($values[mt_rand(0, $max)]);
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomString($length) {
  $salt = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));
  $maxIndex = count($salt) - 1;

  $result = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $index = mt_rand(0, $maxIndex);
    $result .= $salt[$index];
  }
  return $result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: [PHP Function that Generates Random Characters](http://carlofontanos.com/php-function-that-generates-random-characters/)

This PHP function worked for me:

```
function cvf_ps_generate_random_code($length=10) {

   $string = '';
   // You can define your own characters here.
   $characters = "23456789ABCDEFHJKLMNPRTVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

   for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
       $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
   }

   return $string;

}
```

Usage:

```
echo cvf_ps_generate_random_code(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function generates pseudo string of **any** length.

```
/**
 * Returns random string of a given length.
 */
function get_random_string($length) {
  $pull = [];
  while (count($pull) < $length) {
    $pull = array_merge($pull, range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
  }
  shuffle($pull);
  return substr(implode($pull), 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it totally wrong, because you're depending on numbers, not characters and I am not sure if you want the random output to be just numbers, if so why the need to get all the alphabetic letters and all numbers and extract their length? Why not you just use `rand(0, 62)`?, even though you've forgot to initialize your variable `$randstring` before you declare the function.

Anyway, PHP offers you a very handy function for this purpose. It's `str_shuffle()`. Here is an example that suits your need.

```html
<?php

function randomString() {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    return str_shuffle($characters);
}
echo randomString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found a solution to get random and unique values.

My solution is:

```
substr(md5(time()), 0, 12)
```

`time` always return a timestamp, and it is always unique. You can use it with MD5 to make it better.

Comment: Timestamp is **not** always unique and md5 does not make it better. If multiple threads run within the same second, this code will generate the same string for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

A class with some of the functions from the discussions above.

```
$options['numeric'] = true;
$options['uppercase'] = true;
$options['lowercase'] = true;
$new = new RandomString($options);

class RandomString
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $default = ['numeric' => true, 'uppercase' => true, 'lowercase' => true];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * array
     */
    private $whitelist = ['numeric', 'uppercase', 'lowercase'];

    /**
     * RandomString constructor.
     *
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(array $options = [])
    {
        $this->options = $this->default;
        if(!empty($options))
        {
            $options = array_intersect_key($options, array_flip($this->whitelist));
            if(empty($options))
            {
                $this->options = $this->default;
            }else
            {
                $this->options = $options;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private function returnCharacters(){

        $options = $this->options;

        $numbers = '0123456789';
        $uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        $characters = '';
        if(isset($options['numeric']) && $options['numeric'] === true){
            $characters .= $numbers;
        }

        if(isset($options['uppercase']) && $options['uppercase'] === true){
            $characters .= $uppercase;
        }

        if(isset($options['lowercase']) && $options['lowercase'] === true){
            $characters .= $lowercase;
        }
        return $characters;
    }

    /**
     * @param $length
     * @param $quantity
     * @return string
     */
    public function randomString($length, $quantity) {

        $string = '';
        $characters = $this->returnCharacters();

        for ($j = 0; $j < $quantity; $j++) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
                $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
            }
            $string .= "\n";
        }
        return $string;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->options;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getWhitelist()
    {
        return $this->whitelist;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this method, you can choose the character length while creating.

```
<?php
    $random_string = "";
    $character_count = 12;
    for($i=1; $i <= $character_count; $i++)
    {
        $random_string .= chr(rand(97, 122));
    }
    echo $random_string;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it can generate up to length of master. but its simple and fit for small string.

```
$master="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$master_array = str_split($master);
shuffle($master_array);
print_r(implode("",array_slice($master_array,0,10)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    /**
     * Creates a random string
     *
     * @param (int) $length
     *   Length in characters
     * @param (array) $ranges
     *   (optional) Array of ranges to be used
     *
     * @return
     * Random string
    */
    function random_string($length, $ranges = array('0-9', 'a-z', 'A-Z')) {
        foreach ($ranges as $r) $s .= implode(range(array_shift($r = explode('-', $r)), $r[1]));
        while (strlen($s) < $length) $s .= $s;
        return substr(str_shuffle($s), 0, $length);
    }

    // Examples:
    $l = 100;
    echo '<b>Default:</b> ' . random_string($l) . '<br />';
    echo '<b>Lower Case only:</b> ' . random_string($l, array('a-z')) . '<br />';
    echo '<b>HEX only:</b> ' . random_string($l, array('0-9', 'A-F')) . '<br />';
    echo '<b>BIN only:</b> ' . random_string($l, array('0-1')) . '<br />';

/* End of file */
```

Comment: if you want to be using proper PHP, replace the first line of the function with                        `foreach ($ranges as $r) $s .= implode('', range(array_shift($r = explode('-', $r)), $r[1]));`

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomString() {
       return md5(rand(100, 200));
}
```

Comment: This is only partly random, since you are limiting it to 100 unique combinations. Additionally, md5 will always return a string with 32 characters length. Good for general usage, but not if you need a huge amount of truly unique strings. See my answer for an example with better randomness using the current time, md5() and `base64_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this random string in a place where a user might see it or use it (eg as a password generator, you might want to limit the set of characters used to exclude vowels.  That way you will not accidentally generate bad words and offend someone.  Don't laugh it happens.

Comment: Also, I would add that you shouldn't include visually similar characters, e.g. `1=>l (lowercase L), 0 (digit)=>O (letter)`. These can be confusing to the user since they look similar at first glance, so only stick to the distinct ones.

Answer (score 0):

I say take the best of several answers and put them together - str_suffle and range are new to me:

```
echo generateRandomString(25); // Example of calling it

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(implode(array_merge(range(0,9), range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z')))), 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: This is limited to 62 characters, due to the fact that you are simply concatenating the 3 ranges (0-9, a-z, A-Z) in a 62 long string and then shuffling the characters and getting the first N characters (so N can be at most 62). The function can be reworked to make a recursive call to itself when a length of more than 62 characters is requested, but just wanted to point out the current limit for anyone reading this.

Comment: a lot of effort for little entropy here... you can do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = array_merge(range('0', '9'), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
echo join('', array_map(function() use($t) { return $t[array_rand($t)]; }, range(1, 15)));
```

or one-liner

```
echo join('', array_map(function() { return substr('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', rand(0, 61), 1); }, range(1, 15)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I always liked to use base64 for generating random passwords or other random (printable) character strings. The usage of base64 ensures a large number of printable characters is available.

On the shell, I usually do something like this:

```
base64 < /dev/urandom |head -c10
```

Something similar can be done in PHP as well. However reading directly from /dev/urandom might be forbidden by open_basedir restrictions. So this is what I've arrived at:

```
base64_encode(
    join(
        '',
        array_map(
            function($x){ return chr(mt_rand(1,255));},
            range(1,15)
        )
    )
);
```

To get a truly random string, we need random input as well. This is what the `join/array_map` does. Using something like `uniqid` is not enough, because it will always have a similar prefix, as it's basically a glorified timestamp.

If you have the openssl extension installed, you can of course use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead, which would be even better.

Comment: Yes, use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` if you can! Don't settle for `mt_rand()`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31107425/2224584) for an implementation that uses a CSPRNG.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this my function to generate a custom random alphanumeric string:

```
<?php
  function random_alphanumeric($length) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345689';
    $my_string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $pos = random_int(0, strlen($chars) -1);
      $my_string .= substr($chars, $pos, 1);
    }
    return $my_string;
  }
?>
```

You can adjust the result by passing the length of the string to the function like below:

```
  $test_with_50_items = random_alphanumeric(50); // 50 characters
  echo $test_with_50_items;
```

Example (test_with_50_items): `Y1FypdjVbFCFK6Gh9FDJpe6dciwJEfV6MQGpJqAfuijaYSZ86`

If you need more than 50 chars or less simply call the function how you like:

```
  $test_with_27_items = random_alphanumeric(27); // 27 characters
  echo $test_with_27_items;
```

If you need two or more unique strings you can do by loop using `while` so you are sure to get two unique strings... you can do the same with more strings, the only limit is your fantasy...

```
  $string_1 = random_alphanumeric(50);
  $string_2 = random_alphanumeric(50);
  while ($string_1 == $string_2) {
    $string_1 = random_alphanumeric(50);
    $string_2 = random_alphanumeric(50);
    if ($string_1 != $string_2) {
       break;
    }
  }
  echo $string_1;
  echo "<br>\n";
  echo $string_2;
```

$string_1: `KkvUwia8rbDEV2aChWqm3AgeUZqyrRbUx2AxVhx5s4TSJ2VwA4`

$string_2: `XraO85YfxBBCInafvwipSOJwLmk6JMWiuWOxYQDnXohcn2D8K6`

According to PHP 8.3 random_int() is "secure by default"

Answer (score 0):

```
function strgen($len) {
    $buf = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $j = mt_rand(0, 61);
        if ($j >= 36) {
            $j += 13;
        } else if ($j >= 10) {
            $j += 7;
        }
        $buf .= chr(48 + $j);
    }
    return $buf;
}
```

Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

IF YOUR ARE USING PHP 7 +

```
public function generateRandom(){

$string = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10)); // 20 chars

// OR

$string = base64_encode(random_bytes(10)); // ~14 characters, includes /=+

// or

$string = substr(str_replace(['+', '/', '='], '', base64_encode(random_bytes(32))), 0, 32); // 32 characters, without /=+

// or

$string = bin2hex(random_bytes(10)); // 20 characters, only 0-9a-f

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help:

This function will return random string with length between `$maxLength` and `$minLength`.

**NOTE:** Function `random_bytes` works since PHP 7.

If you need specific length, so `$maxLength` and `$minLength` **must be same**.

```
function getRandomString($maxLength = 20, $minLength = 10)
{
    $minLength = $maxLength < $minLength ? $maxLength : $minLength;
    $halfMin = ceil($minLength / 2);
    $halfMax = ceil($maxLength / 2);
    $bytes = random_bytes(rand($halfMin, $halfMax));
    $randomString = bin2hex($bytes);
    $randomString = strlen($randomString) > $maxLength ? substr($randomString, 0, -1) : $randomString;
    return $randomString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A full solution (class plus test), partly based on some suggestions above...

```
class TokenFactory
{
    private const LENGTH = 12;
    private const ALLOWED = '123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ~!@#$%^&*{}';
    private const MIN_NUMBER_OF_DIGITS = 1;
    private const MIN_NUMBER_OF_CAPS = 1;
    private const MIN_NUMBER_OF_SPECIALS = 1;
    private const MIN_NUMBER_OF_LETTERS = 1;

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function make(): string
    {
        $pass = $this->generateToken();

        if ($this->isTokenValid($pass)) {
            return $pass;
        } else {
            return $this->make();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function generateToken(): string
    {
        $allowedCharacters = self::ALLOWED;
        $token              = '';
        $max               = mb_strlen($allowedCharacters, '8bit') - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < self::LENGTH; ++$i) {
            $token .= $allowedCharacters[random_int(0, $max)];
        }
        return $token;
    }

    /**
     * @param $token
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isTokenValid($token): bool
    {
        $numberOfDigits   = preg_match_all("/[0-9]/", $token);
        $numberOfCaps     = preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $token);
        $numberOfSpecials = preg_match_all("/[~!@#\$%^&*{}]/", $token);
        $numberOfLetters  = preg_match_all("/[a-z]/", $token);

        return
            $numberOfDigits > self::MIN_NUMBER_OF_DIGITS
            && $numberOfCaps > self::MIN_NUMBER_OF_CAPS
            && $numberOfSpecials > self::MIN_NUMBER_OF_SPECIALS
            && $numberOfLetters > self::MIN_NUMBER_OF_LETTERS
            ;
    }
}

class TokenFactoryTest
{
    public function test_correct_syntax()
    {
        /**
         * Arrange
         */
        $length = 12;
        $numberOfChecks = 1000;

        /**
         * Act & Assert
         */
        $class = new TokenFactory();

        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $numberOfChecks) {
            $generatedToken = $class->make();

            $numberOfDigits = preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $generatedToken );
            $numberOfCaps = preg_match_all( "/[A-Z]/", $generatedToken );
            $numberOfSpecials   = preg_match_all("/[~!@#\$%^&*{}]/", $generatedToken);
            $numberOfLetters   = preg_match_all("/[a-z]/", $generatedToken);

            Assert::assertEquals($length, strlen($generatedToken));
            Assert::assertTrue($numberOfDigits >= 1, 'Digit error: ' . $generatedToken);
            Assert::assertTrue($numberOfCaps >= 1, 'Caps error: ' . $generatedToken);
            Assert::assertTrue($numberOfSpecials >= 1, 'Specials error: ' . $generatedToken);
            Assert::assertTrue($numberOfLetters >= 1, 'Letters error: ' . $generatedToken);

            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW make sure to catch that exception somewhere where it suits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

If you are morbidly scared of typing out letters of the alphabet, don't care about string security, and are only interested in alphabets, here's a neat solution

```php
$alphabets = range ("a", "z");
shuffle ($alphabets);
$randomString = substr(implode ("", $alphabets), 3, 17); // adjust according to desired length
```

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel solution:**
If you are using Laravel Framework, you can use its StringHelper like this.

`use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

`Str::random($strlentgh = 16)`

Answer (score 0):

recursive solution:

```
public static function _random(string $set , int $length): string
{
    $setLength = strlen($set);
    $randomKey = random_int(0, $setLength - 1);

    $firstPiece = substr($set, 0, $randomKey);
    $secondPiece = substr($set, $randomKey, $setLength - $randomKey);

    $removedCharacter = $firstPiece[strlen($firstPiece) - 1] ?? null;
    if(null === $removedCharacter || $length === 0) {
        return '';
    }
    $firstPieceWithoutTheLastChar = substr($firstPiece, 0, -1);

    return $removedCharacter . self::_random($firstPieceWithoutTheLastChar . $secondPiece, $length - 1);
}
```

nice performance , https://3v4l.org/aXaJ6/perf

Answer (score 0):

I wanted pseudorandom strings of specific characters and a preset length.  I wanted the highest quality pseudorandomness practically possible for the current version of PHP, at this time it could be v5, v6, v7, or v8, and it could be using default configuration or special.  To tame this chaos, I sampled several of the other answers here and included function availability conditionals.

Usage.  To use it globally assign `$VALID_ID_CHARS` with whatever characters you want and then call it:

```
$VALID_ID_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
$myNewRandomId = makeId(6);
```

```
function makeId($desiredLen)
{
    global $VALID_ID_CHARS;
    if ($desiredLen < 1) {
        throw new \RangeException("Length must be a positive integer");
    }
    $vLen = 0;
    if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
        $vLen = mb_strlen($VALID_ID_CHARS, '8bit') - 1;
    } else {
        $vLen = strlen($VALID_ID_CHARS) - 1;
    }
    if (function_exists('random_int')) {
        $pieces = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $desiredLen; ++$i) {
            $pieces[] = $VALID_ID_CHARS[random_int(0, $vLen)];
        }
        return implode('', $pieces);
    }
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        $random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($desiredLen);
        $id = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $desiredLen; ++$i) {
            $id .= $VALID_ID_CHARS[ord($random[$i]) % $vLen];
        }
        return $id;
    }
    http_response_code(500);
    die('random id generation failed. either random_int or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes is needed');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need large number of random strings with no duplicates, here's a recursive code with small modification:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10)
{
    global $generatedStrings;
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    if (isset($generatedStrings[$randomString])) {
        $randomString = generateRandomString($length);
    }
    $generatedStrings[$randomString] = $randomString;
    return $randomString;
}

$generatedStrings = array();

foreach(range(1, 100000) as $num) {
    echo "\n".$num."\t : ".generateRandomString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function generate_name ($length = LENGTH_IMG_PATH) {
    $image_name = "";
    $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    $i = 0;

    while ($i < $length) {

        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);

        if (!strstr($image_name, $char)) {
            $image_name .= $char;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $image_name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get it in a single line, try this:

```
$str = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 5)), 0, $length);
```

Comment: After 65,536 random strings generated this way, you can expect to have generated the same string twice, even with an arbitrarily large `$length`. Weak PRNGs produce collisions (and are predictable!)

Comment: str_shuffle — Randomly shuffles a string according to the PHP docs. So how could you tell that it is not going to be same string twice.

Answer (score -1):

Previous answers generate passwords that are insecure or difficult to type.

This one is secure and provides a password that users are more likely to actually use, instead of being discarded for something weak.

```
// NOTE: On PHP 5.x you will need to install https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

/**
 * Generate a password that can easily be typed by users.
 *
 * By default, this will sacrifice strength by skipping characters that can cause
 * confusion. Set $allowAmbiguous to allow these characters.
 */
static public function generatePassword($length=12, $mixedCase=true, $numericCount=2, $symbolCount=1, $allowAmbiguous=false, $allowRepeatingCharacters=false)
{
  // sanity check to prevent endless loop
  if ($numericCount + $symbolCount > $length) {
    throw new \Exception('generatePassword(): $numericCount + $symbolCount are too high');
  }

  // generate a basic password with just alphabetic characters
  $chars  = 'qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnm';
  if ($mixedCase) {
    $chars .= 'QWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNML';
  }
  if ($allowAmbiguous) {
    $chars .= 'iol';
    if ($mixedCase) {
      $chars .= 'IO';
    }
  }

  $password = '';
  foreach (range(1, $length) as $index) {
    $char = $chars[random_int(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];

    if (!$allowRepeatingCharacters) {
      while ($char == substr($password, -1)) {
        $char = $chars[random_int(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
      }
    }

    $password .= $char;
  }


  // add numeric characters
  $takenSubstitutionIndexes = [];

  if ($numericCount > 0) {
    $chars = '23456789';
    if ($allowAmbiguous) {
      $chars .= '10';
    }

    foreach (range(1, $numericCount) as $_) {
      $index = random_int(0, strlen($password) - 1);
      while (in_array($index, $takenSubstitutionIndexes)) {
        $index = random_int(0, strlen($password) - 1);
      }

      $char = $chars[random_int(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
      if (!$allowRepeatingCharacters) {
        while (substr($password, $index - 1, 1) == $char || substr($password, $index + 1, 1) == $char) {
          $char = $chars[random_int(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
        }
      }

      $password[$index] = $char;
      $takenSubstitutionIndexes[] = $index;
    }
  }

  // add symbols
  $chars = '!@#$%&*=+?';
  if ($allowAmbiguous) {
    $chars .= '^~-_()[{]};:|\\/,.\'"`<>';
  }

  if ($symbolCount > 0) {
    foreach (range(1, $symbolCount) as $_) {
      $index = random_int(0, strlen($password) - 1);
      while (in_array($index, $takenSubstitutionIndexes)) {
        $index = random_int(0, strlen($password) - 1);
      }

      $char = $chars[random_int(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
      if (!$allowRepeatingCharacters) {
        while (substr($password, $index - 1, 1) == $char || substr($password, $index + 1, 1) == $char) {
          $char = $chars[random_int(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
        }
      }

      $password[$index] = $char;
      $takenSubstitutionIndexes[] = $index;
    }
  }

  return $password;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The one line solution will be

```
str_shuffle(base64_encode(date('mdyhis').date('mdyhis')));
```

Comment: This is even remotely random. Do not use this, please.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 things wrong with your code:

1. $randstring is not assigned to anything (only inside the function which is out of scope).
2. RandomString only returns the last random charactor. Replace `=` with `.=`.
3. `Rand` does not generate cryptographically secure pseudo-random numbers. Use `random_int` instead.

See below:

```
<?php
    function RandomString()
    {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randstring = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $randstring .= $characters[random_int(0, strlen($characters))];
        }
        return $randstring;
    }
    $randstring = RandomString();
    echo $randstring;
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers?

Comment: this at some point raises this error => Uninitialized string offset:

Answer (score -2):

```
$pass = "";
for ($i=0;$i<12;++$i)
  $pass.= ($r=mt_rand(0,35))<26?chr(ord('a')+$r):chr(ord('0')+$r-26);
```

Comment: `$pass = "";` line missed :)