# Php - Random string with fixed regexp

Tags: php, generated-code

Regarding this:

[Generating a unique random string of a certain length and restrictions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444877/generating-a-unique-random-string-of-a-certain-length-and-restrictions-in-php)

I want it evolved:

```
function getRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $string = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

How can I do random 8 chars but with 5 digits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your modified function:

```
function getRandomString( $length = 8 ) 
{
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $digits     = '0123456789';
    $string     = '';

    for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )
    {
        $string .= $digits[ mt_rand( 0, strlen( $digits ) - 1 ) ];
    }

    for( $i = 5; $i < $length; $i++ ) 
    {
        $string .= $characters[ mt_rand( 0, strlen( $characters ) - 1 ) ];
    }

    $array = str_split( $string );
    shuffle( $array );
    return implode( '', $array );
}
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/tLUq7)**</kbd>

Starting from your function, we divide `$characters` in `$characters` and `$digits`, then we add to the empty string 5 random digits and remaining random characters.

At the end, we shuffle resulting string and return it.

#### Variant (not-repeating characters):

```
function getRandomString( $length = 8 )
{
    $characters = str_split( 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' );
    $digits     = str_split( '0123456789' );

    shuffle( $characters );
    shuffle( $digits );
    
    $retval = array_merge
    (
        array_slice( $digits, 0, 5 ), 
        array_slice( $characters, 0, $length-5 )
    );
  
    shuffle( $retval );
    
    return implode( '', $retval );
}
```

We start directly with arrays: `$characters` and `$digits`, then we shuffle them, we extract 5 digit items and remaining character items, merging them in `$retval` array.

At the end, we shuffle `$retval` array and return it imploded as string.

---

Edit: precedent version 3 digits / 5 chars; actual version: 5 digits / 3 chars

Answer (score 0):

function getRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789');

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $rand = '';
    foreach (array_rand($characters, 5) as $k) $rand .= $characters[$k];
    $string[$i] = $rand;
}

return $string;
```

}

http://ideone.com/SSg3m4