# Combine random letters and numbers

Tags: php, random, numbers, captcha, letters

Does any of you know how to add random letters aswel as random numbers.
thanks for you help.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$image = imagecreate(, ); 
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, , ,);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, , , ); 
$code = rand(00, 99); 




$_SESSION['code'] = ($code);
imagestring($image, , , , $code, $textcolor); 
header ("Content-type: image/png"); 
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a function for it

```
function createRandomString() {
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $i = 0;
    $randomstring = '' ;

    while ($i <= 7) {
        $num = rand() % 33;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $randomstring = $randomstring . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }

    return $randomstring;

}

echo createRandomString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like to do this for random letters and numbers using md5. its not completely random, but it still returns a random string with both numbers and letters.

```
$i = rand(100000000, 9999999999)
$i = md5($i);           //creates a hashed string with 32 characters
$i = str_split($i, 10); //10 is the amount of characters of your string max 32
$i = $i[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
<?php
$code = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),10);
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $code, $textcolor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Sources used:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438778/1978142 
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.imagestring.php