# Scratch generate by openssl_random_pseudo_bytes PHP

Tags: php, openssl

I need to create a function to generate a string for scratching.

I was recommended to use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() function on php. But it generate a result which contains some special ascii character like ����P. When I use bin2hex it's ok but it doesn't contains other character like w,q...

Is there some other methods?

Comment: What's the range of characters you wish to generate?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `bin2hex()` gives you a hexadecimal representation of the binary values. Hexadecimal can only represent 0-9 and A-F since it's a base 16 number system. However, you could do something like the first answer to this question: [PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator) to generate random strings with Qs and Ws.