# How to make "uniqid" only give numbers?

Tags: php

I have the following code which I have put together from different tutorial examples:

```
<?php

$stamp = date("Ymdhis");
$random_id_length = 6;
$rndid = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1)); 
$rndid = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndid)); 
$rndid = str_replace(".","",$rndid); 
$rndid = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndid));
$rndid = substr($rndid,0,$random_id_length); 
$orderid = "$stamp-$rndid";
$orderid = str_replace(".", "", "$orderid");
echo($orderid);

?>
```

FIDDLE: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/27d-qfw

I would like this to create a number; the current time, followed by a 6 digit random number.

For example: `20130710045730-954762`

However at the moment the random digits also include letters.

For example: `20130710045730-Z3sVN2`

How can I edit the code to just include numbers? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just map letters to numbers?

Comment: you could use `str_pad(rand(0,999999),6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)` you have a 1 in a million chance of a collision for posts in the same second.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`uniqid()` will already return numbers. But in their hexadecimal representation. In general you could just convert them to decimals:

```
echo hexdec(uniqid());
```

The value can only meaningful being observed on a 64 bit system as it is very large and beyond the limits of an 32bit signed integer (like php's one). And that's the point. `uniqid()` uses such large numbers together with other techniques to ensure a high grade of uniqness. **If you are using only 6 digits, you cannot grant this anymore.** The risk that values will collide will be high.

I would suggest to generate an application wide uniqness using an auto_increment value in a database or something similar to that.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a random string, use something like this:

```
$stamp = date("Ymdhis");
$random_id_length = 6;
$rndid = generateRandomString( $random_id_length );

$orderid = $stamp ."-". $rndid;
echo($orderid);

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
  $characters = '0123456789';
  $randomString = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
  }
  return $randomString;
}

// Output example: 20130710055714-462231
```

Example: http://codepad.org/eukiOb6S

Fn modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356295/1265817

Comment: Thanks! That's perefct :-)

Comment: No problem at all! If you find the answer to be correct, please mark it correct for future users, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.I think this will be help.

rand(100000,999999)

Enter the two number which digit number do you want

Comment: i think both are same @ceejayoz

Comment: http://php.net/mt_rand says it is, at the very least, much faster, and uses known randomness characteristics. It should be used instead of `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
str_pad(rand(0,'9'.round(microtime(true))),11, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Add further explanation of why this will work and why OP wasn't getting it right

Comment: please visit this link for more details [http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php] . And round(microtime(true)) always calls the microtime..