# Random string to generate a new image each time page loads

Tags: php, image, rendering, render

What I want to do is have a new image generated when the page is loaded. I have the random string working, but the image won't generate. If I assign it a normal name, not a variable, it'll generate perfectly fine, permissions are set, etc.. Not exactly sure what to do to get it to create the image

Here's the code that works.

```
 $chart->render("generated/chart.png");

// But it isn't dynamic, like I want it to be
print "<center><img src=generated/$char.png></center>";
```

Here's the code that doesn't work. So I had the idea of using a random string generator to make a random name for the image, and just do that.

```
// random string code
$length = 10;

$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);



$chart->setTitle("Mini Mood Map");
// THIS is the line giving me problems, I've tried different quotes with no luck

$chart->render(generated/$randomString.png);

// Broken image
print "<center><img src=generated/$randomString.png></center>";
```

Sorry, I have a bad cold and my heads not on tight tonight. Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator... many examples

Comment: I think he wants the filename header to be random so that the file won't cache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note how the original is quoted:

```
$chart->render("generated/chart.png");
```

You need to do the same:

```
$chart->render("generated/" . $randomString . ".png");
```

Comment: Works! I just couldn't figure the syntax!