# How to Shuffle array

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I am using this table to generate password. I am using this code to shuffle and it shuffles only rows and not columns randomly. I want to place them randomly in tables mixing both rows and column values.

```
$matrix=array();
$matrix[3][0]="h5";$matrix[3][1]="h3";$matrix[3][2]="96";$matrix[3][3]="45";$matrix[3][4]="oo";
$matrix[1][0]="39";$matrix[1][1]="k4";$matrix[1][2]="i2";$matrix[1][3]="j9";$matrix[1][4]="g5";
$matrix[0][0]="t1";$matrix[0][1]="2j";$matrix[0][2]="r3";$matrix[0][3]="f8";$matrix[0][4]="y9";
$matrix[4][0]="i3";$matrix[4][1]="k7";$matrix[4][2]="a1";$matrix[4][3]="e3";$matrix[4][4]="f6";
$matrix[2][0]="t9";$matrix[2][1]="e2";$matrix[2][2]="w3";$matrix[2][3]="r2";$matrix[2][4]="w3";
shuffle($matrix);
//Shuffle the array
foreach($matrix as $key => $value) {
echo "$value
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this.

Comment: http://in3.php.net/shuffle

Comment: You can try shuffle function (buld-in php functions)
Check manual at: [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle)

Comment: i hope your not using this to protect anything important

Comment: @Johnny , OP had already used `shuffle`.. see the code.

Comment: I tried a lot of couldn't make it work. Is it possible to help me change the script in my post?

Comment: @Johnny - I tried it but the only the rows shuffle and not the columns.

Comment: what version of php are you using? do you just want to reorder the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$shuffled_ = array();
$shuffled = array();

foreach( $matrix as $val )
    foreach($val as $v)
        $shuffled_[] = $v;

shuffle($shuffled_);

foreach( $shuffled_ as $key => $val )
    $shuffled[ floor($key / 5) ][$key % 5] = $val;
```

Comment: Now I see columns getting shuffled randomly and that's a good one. But I see the same rows values getting shuffled and I need to shuffle rows similar to columns.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to dump all values into a single string, shuffle that and slice out a new password:

```
$original = 't9w3w3r2e296h3ooh545i2g5k439j9r3t1f82jy9e3f6a1k7i3';
$password = substr(str_shuffle($original), 0, 6); // generate 6-char password
```

Though, for password generation I would recommend using [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator/22829048#22829048) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your $matrix is  multidimensional (specifically twodimensional) array, one foreach will just output the array, I think this is what u need

```
foreach($matrix as $matrixChild) {
    shuffle($matrixChild); // updated
    foreach ($matrixChild as $k => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

btw, why don't u use usual standard random string generator, smth like this

```
function generatePassword ($length = 8){
    $password = "";
    $i = 0;
    $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    while ($i < $length){
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);

        if (!strstr($password, $char)) {
            $password .= $char;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $password;
}
```