# Redirect with email on "?" strange code

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm doing a system to reset password and I need pass email on URL like this:

```
http://example.com/reset?email=email@domain.com&token=89s8ads9
```

I'm doing this:

```
    return $this->redirect(array(
        'controller'=> 'site',
        'action'=> 'resetaSenha',
        '?'=> array('email'=> 'email=email@domain.com', 'token'=> 89s8ads9)
        )
    );
```

But is returning this:

```
http://example.com/reset?email=email%40domain.com&token=89s8ads9
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem more detailed? If the problem is `%40`, it actually shouldn't be a problem as `%40` will be decoded to `@`

Comment: Exactly, now I realize that cakephp decode so if I access $this->request->query['email'] on controller they give me the email decoded in the right way.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect with e-mail?  Are you sending it?

Comment: plug the randomly generated string directly from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator into the e-mail, then store it as the recovery key temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did'nt realized that even on url with ?email=email%40domain, when we access from controller $this->request->query['email'], we obtain the email decoded in the right way email@domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

`%40` is @ urlencoded.

Something in your code is converting @ to %40 for you.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

You can decode it with `urlencode($_GET['email']);` which will replace the %40 with an @

Answer (score -2):

Do a captcha check, and deny access to the e-mail sender after the session var is unset.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It technically does a redirect, when the e-mail is sent.  That's the strangest thing I can think of with e-mail redirection, since a simple URL referring to a token checker is incredibly easy to do.

Comment: While that may be true, it's not an answer to the question the user was asking.

Comment: now it's marked as a cake issue, I'm lost with the question.  if it was real PHP I could help better.