# Creating a unique 8 digit number and inserting it into a database without duplicates

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a unique URL number of each page in my website to include it into a sitemap easily. My urls look like this : `site.com/book/11111111`, `site.com/book/11111112`

I want to insert a unique URL for each ID, but stuck with a little problem. I use the code below, and it doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of my `thing_url` for every time. I can check its uniqueness with an if-else statement but even I check it for the second time, my string may or may not be unique for the second time, either. I don't want to have lots of variables and if-else statements using `$thing_url`, `$thing_url2`, `$thing_url3`, etc.

Is there a way to check the uniqueness using a single loop, until it succeed? Here's what I do now.

```
$thing_name = $_POST['thing_name']; // form value
$thing_url = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999); // generates 8 digit numeric string

$query = "SELECT thing_url FROM thing WHERE thing_url = '$thing_url'";
$result = $sqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$finish = $row['thing_url'];

if($finish == $thing_url) {
    echo "Bad luck";
} else {
 $thing = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO thing(thing_url, thing_name ) VALUES (?,?)"); // prepare
    $thing->bind_param("ss", $thing_url, $thing_name); // bind
    $thing->execute(); // execute
    $thing->close(); // close
}
```

Comment: Use autoincrement id. Here are more informations http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: I already use auto_incremented ID for each record and they're unique, but I want to use these thing_url's as a unique URL. auto_increment ID values are easy to guess and I don't want my site content to be crawled that easy.

Comment: And crawling ids from 1000000 to 999999 is much harder?

Comment: @u_mulder, I laughed so hard :D That's correct. but I want to make it a little harder, will change URL structure to SEF url's soon, but know I don't want to mess with htaccess much.

Comment: You can use random string for example 64 chars are much enough for your app :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generatorand use one function with while to check it uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients should never try to generate anything unique (other than a GUID) due to this type of synchronization issue.  Instead, a central coordinator should have that responsibility.

In your case the ideal coordinator is your database, MySQL.  You can use the primary key of your URL (from thing_url) as the unique identifier.  That will work fine as long as the database is following the typical pattern of incrementing the primary key by 1 and you started at a low number (usually 1).

> I already use auto_incremented ID for each record and they're unique, but I want to use these thing_url's as a unique URL. auto_increment ID values are easy to guess and I don't want my site content to be crawled that easy

Then permute the ID in some [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) manner, e.g. XOR with some bit pattern, rotate the bits, swap the bytes, etc.