# Creating a 14 character 'random key generator'

Tags: php, codeigniter, lamp

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter to write up a small program for school which generates a random 'key' every time I click the 'generate' button. Looking to see if there's a way for me to create a function where I can fill up a 14 character array with a random number or letter and then set the array to a variable which I can call upon to display as my generated key.

Any and all help would be much appreciated as I am new to CodeIgniter.

Comment: Why does this have the CSS tag?

Comment: sorry, i'm also using CSS in my code but realized that it's not part of the problem i'm running into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while back I wrote this function in PHP, it does what it does and gives you some flexibility as well through complexity modifiers, I used a default set of 5 different 'levels' of characters and the length is also variable ofcourse.

I'm just going to chuck it in here and 'try' to explain what is going on as well as I can by comments:

```
function rsg($length = 10, $complexity = 2) {
        //available 'complexity' subsets of characters
        $charSubSets = array(
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
            '0123456789',
            '!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:">?<[]\\\';,.`~',
            'µñ©æáßðøäåé®þüúíóö'
        );

        // will be filled with subsets from above $charSubsets
        $chars = '';

        //concact each subset until complexity is reached onto the $chars variable
        for ($i = 0; $i < $complexity; $i++)
            $chars .= $charSubSets[$i];

        //create array containing a single char per entry from the combined subset in the $chars variable.
        $chars = str_split($chars);
        //define length of array for mt_rand limit
        $charCount = (count($chars) - 1);
        //create string to return
        $string = '';
        //idk why I used a while but it won't really hurt you when the string is less than 100000 chars long ;)
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $length) {
            $randomNumber = mt_rand(0, $charCount); //generate number within array index range
            $string .= $chars[$randomNumber]; //get that character out of the array
            $i++; //increment counter
        }

        return $string; //return string created from random characters
    }
```

This is what I currently use and it has satisfied my needs for quite some time now, if anyone reading over this has improvements I'd love to hear them as well!

Comment: i originally had this --

function random($len = 14)
 {
  $chars = array(
   'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
   'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
   'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
   'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
   '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
   );
  
  shuffle($chars);

  $num_chars = count($chars) - 1;

  for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
  {
   $token .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $num_chars)];
  }
  return $token;
 }


and it didn't seem to like it

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=array(rand(10000000000000, 99999999999999));
```

is a quick way to get a 14 digit array.

Comment: `mt_rand()` does a better job than `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how random you want it to be. You could specify all characters you want in a `$characters` string, then just create a string up to `$length`, picking a random substring of length 1 from the characters string.

What are the requirements?
Do you want it to be as random as possible ([This link might be useful](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php))
Are multiple occurrences of one character allowed in one random string?

Here's an example though: [PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)