# randomString Function Generates error?

Tags: php

I am writing a Authentication class in PHP and when i have the following function,

```
private function randomString($length = 50) {
    $characters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $string = '';

    for ($p=0; $p < $length; $p++) { 
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

i get the following error:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 36
```

I am new to creating classes so i don't know what i have done wrong here. or is there a better method of generating a random string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP random string generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last char index is 35, you need to use `strlen(...)-1`:

```
$string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
```