# Generating a unique value in php

Tags: php, html, function, md5, uniqueidentifier

I am considering options to use in generating a 5 character unique string in php. Or if anyone have a better option. I'm not sure if substr will actually reduces the reliability of the uniqueness as well. All advise appreciated.

Option1:

```
$unique_id=substr(md5(time()), -5);
```

OR

Option2:

```
$unique_id=substr(uniqid, -5);
```

Comment: you can use first three character static and embed only two character at last it is useful for to easy identified if you use random then after when there is no of data is large then may be it match with some existing one

Comment: Solution could be here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator

Comment: Option 3: Using PHP's [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), that does exactly this, creates an ID based on the time, just heed the warning in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This In built php function could help you.

```
rand(min,max);
```

Comment: This won't be unique then? Two users/strings can be the same.

Comment: if you are storing in Db table, then you can test its duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with first option, but instead use something more like:

md5(uniqid(rand(), true))

Answer (score -1):

Use, as @Sagar said, the

```
rand(min,max);
```

Then store the values in a database. Before you're giving the users the random number, check if it already exists in the database. If it doesn't, move on and insert to the database.

Something like this:

```
$rand = rand(min,max);

    $sql = "SELECT randomNum FROM users WHERE randomNum = '$rand'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count != 1){
        //insert to database
    }
```