# Random unique alpha numeric link generate on submit

Tags: php

How can I write a script that will generate a random unique link on submit in PHP?

Currently when a user clicks a button, a on submit URL is generated in numbers. E.g.: `http://rcpaste.com/20/`.

But I would like to generate a random alphanumerical code instead of purely a numerical one, how can I do this?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4356289/3933332

Comment: Why does it need to be random? Why not just make a simple count up with alphanumeric in it?

Comment: A random string can not be guaranteed to be unique. That is a contradiction.