# How to get string of fixed length without using rand() function

Tags: php, css

How to get a fixed length string  without using the rand() function?

I have this but I do not want to use the rand() function

```
function generateRandomString($length =6) {
    $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';

    for ($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

  return $randomString;
 }
```

Comment: *"How to get fixed length srting without using rand() function"* `function x(){return "fixed length";}`. (No seriously, why don't you want to use `rand()`?)

Comment: use shuffle instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25672573/5816907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$start=0;$length=6;
$str='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$Val=substr(str_shuffle($str),$start,$length);
echo $Val;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function mt_rand_str ($l, $c = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890') {

     for ($s = '', $cl = strlen($c)-1, $i = 0; $i < $l; $s .= $c[mt_rand(0, $cl)], ++$i);
        return $s;
}
```

Here you can call this function for 8 character

```
mt_rand_str(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to get fixed length random  string

```
<?php
$str = 'abcdef';
$shuffled = str_shuffle($str);

 // this will genrate randome string with fixed string lenght
echo $shuffled;
?>
```