# Is rand() secure to creating an activation number in PHP

Tags: php, random, registration

I want to create an activation number for user registration in PHP

Is rand() Secure ? If not what else I can use ?

*My PHP version : 5.3*

Comment: `Caution
This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.`

Comment: rand is about as random as rolling a dice

Comment: Theres a function here to make a unique string which should work for your purposes:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator/31107425#31107425

Comment: Although this function(random_int()) was added to PHP in PHP 7.0 @MarkBaker

Comment: @SilicaGel That function uses PHP 7.0 random_int()

Comment: I believe it works on php 5.3 using the library mentioned in the comments..  For PHP 5.x, depends on https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat

Comment: As long as you want it for that purpose only, it is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mt_rand() is better than rand()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php