# Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved

Tags: string, php-7

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cezcD.png)

I want Generates a random string.And my develop environment is xampp with php7.0.9. because of references a String class, I got that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP random string generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

Answer (score 8):

is this a cakephp project on php 7, you should
just download the cakephp 2.8 and copy the lib folder from it and replaced to my project.

and Problem Solved

Comment: Where can you download cakephp 2.8? Everything I can find involves using composer etc. and seems pretty complex when all that's needed is replacing a folder? [Update I found it here: https://github.com/Mingyangzu/cakephp-2.8.4]

Answer (score 1):

String is reserved keywords. you can't use String as class names in PHP 7. change it to any other name. like Sting_type.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a class to do this probably. However when you named this class, you named it String.

PHP and other languages have reserved terms that are for internal functions and variables only. We can't use them.

Simply change the classname to something else and it will work normally.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Cakephp project on a PHP 7+ version update your lib folder