# PHP random_bytes returns unreadable characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am using:

```
 random_bytes(30);
```

to generate a random string for my program. This string is then stored in a mysql database. However, when I run the function, I get an output such as

```
T�Ը�@(���m
```

which includes unreadable characters. When I then try to store it in my database, the � characters are not stored and so this means that the string is not properly preserved.

How can I make it so that it returns a string with only readable characters that will not be lost in my mysql database?

Thanks!

Comment: I think some reading about UTF-8 may help you, **but** random bytes??? What were you expecting, the complete works of Shakespear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: It will serve you well to learn some small ampunt abiuyt charcter encodings, a good place to start is ASCII and then unicode, specifically UTF-8 since that is what is generally used for interchange.

Comment: The closest thing to what you were trying to do is probably [`Random::asciiPrintableString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random). That’s all characters that can be printed or seen on the screen. But if you want to use that random string in a URL, for example, you’d want something like `Random::base64UrlString($length)` instead, with characters that don’t need encoding or escaping in a URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

random_bytes generates an arbitrary length string of cryptographic random bytes that are suitable for cryptographic use, such as when generating salts, keys or initialization vectors. use like this

```
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
echo bin2hex($bytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can I just check that the string is still cryptographically secure when you bin2hex it?

Comment: While `random_bytes` generates cryptographically secure random bytes `rand` does not. From thr [PHP `rand` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php): *Caution:
This function does not generate cryptographically secure values*.

Comment: Just encoding random bytes does not change the randomness, hex and Base64 are common ebcodings thrat produce ASCIIcharacters.

Comment: The example code will produce non cryptographically secure psudo random characters in base 62 which is essentially unsuitable for almost all purposes.