# How to generate random & unique 14-digit codes in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to generate millions of random, unique, and digit-only codes in PHP with the fix length of 14. Is there any way to do so? I considered using microtime, but the length of numbers may vary.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why restrict yourself to numbers? I mean, you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31107425/899126), but if you're looking for pretty much guaranteed uniqueness, you'll have a better time with a [uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid)

Comment: @ChrisForrence Thank u for ur comment. I need numbers due to a kind of customer's protocol. I cannot use other characters.

Comment: Do you have a user id or something unique to add to the mix, random generators cannot be unique every time over a long period of time.

Comment: @IdontDownVote Will this always result in 14 digit codes?

Comment: @Ice76 This is why I need to do this using microtime. Microtime seems to guarantee the uniqueness over long periods of time...

Comment: @IdontDownVote You are damn right :-) I preferred a quicker approach :-P

Comment: @RezaKazemifar Micro time wont work as time continues to increase

Comment: @RezaKazemifar and what if two are required to be made within the same second?

Comment: @Ice76 Yep I had cases where 8 were generated within a second. But I think microtime is one millionth of a second and there should be a way to use the micro seconds, huh?

Comment: @IdontDownVote I tested your solution. The length varies and produces something like this: 1.6094913158472E+15 :-(

Comment: @IdontDownVote I should give it more tries as I fear damaging its uniqueness by trimming its length...

Comment: There isn't a way to ensure both randomness and uniqueness in one step. True randomness cannot guarantee uniqueness (because that would mean it wasn't truly random). If you want uniqueness, you will just need to check if the generated value is already in your store of existing codes and regenerate if it is already used.

Comment: @Anthony Thank you Anthony...

Comment: If you want something that is likely "random enough", you could probably use part of microtime and append a random value. You still can't guarantee uniqueness without checking, but you can get close. This would ensure that you  get an incrementing number and if multiple ids are generated in the same increment, the random value appended would also have to be the same. This is kind of how guids can be unique and random with a really low chance of collision. However, 14 digits isn't really that long to guarantee either.

Comment: Also, it is necessary to know if you want it to be a 14-character string, or a 14 digit integer. If '00000000000001' isn't a valid code (because you don't want the leading zeros), then that would reduce your potential set from 99,999,999,999,999 (100 trillion) unique codes to 90,000,000,000,000 (90 trillion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, maybe?

```
function generateByLoop()
{
    $string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {    
        $value = (string) random_int(0,9);
        if ($i === 0) {
            $value = (string) random_int(1,9);
        }

        $string = $string . $value;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Seems a bit of over-engineering if you ask me, but well. And here's another solution based on microtime (which does not involve randomness, but how fast can it be used?)

```
function generateByMicrotime() {
    $microtime = microtime(true);
    $microtime = str_replace('.', '', $microtime);

    echo (substr($microtime, 0, 14));
}
```

Though I must agree with the argument by @Anthony that:

> True randomness cannot guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! How can this be unique?

Comment: The chances of the string NOT being unique exists, but then you could set this in a function looping the output and checking if this actual string does exist in your database and try again. I'm sorry, I cannot come up with any other idea now.

Comment: Thank you very much man... you are great!

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Another option, though, would be using miliseconds (since they roll up to 13 digits) and generating the last one randomly, that should be as close to unique as I can think.

Comment: How is this any different than just doing a single call to random_int? For example: https://3v4l.org/2SrZt

Comment: Nothing really, I just wanted to generate digit by digit which might actually consume more to do than your solution. It probably consumes more. Great solution @Jonathan!

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you man! BTW, what is "cryptographically secure"?

Comment: @RezaKazemifar There are randomly generated values that are used when encrypting data. These values need to be as random as possible to prevent someone from guessing that value. If someone could guess the random value, they could essentially guess the key to decrypt it by repeating whatever method was used to generate the random value in the first place. Having a "cryptographically secure" random generator makes it less likely that the random values can be guessed.

Comment: @Reza. If you are satisfied with the answer, upvote and choose the answer, mate. :)

Comment: @Jonathan I got the point man, thank you very much!

Comment: @Rafael Thanks!