# Laravel Virgin: Set factory sequence in order to ensure that a specified dataset has been created

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, factory

In my application I have the following migrations:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateGridTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grid', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('width');
            $table->unsignedInteger('height');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('grid');
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRoverTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rover', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('grid_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('command');
            $table->foreign('grid_id')->references('id')->on('grid');
            $table->smallInteger('last_commandPos')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->smallInteger('grid_pos_x')->unsigned();
            $table->smallInteger('grid_pos_y')->unsigned();
            $table->enum('rotation', App\Constants\RoverConstants::ORIENTATIONS);
            $table->string('last_command');

            Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rover');
    }
}
```

Creating the tables `grid` and `rover` explicitly. And I want to populate the data via a factory:

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use App\Model\Grid;
use App\Model\Rover;
use App\Constants\RoverConstants;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

/**
 * Random Command Generator based upon:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/13212994/4706711
 * @param integer $length How many characters the wommand will contain.
 * @return string
 */
function generateRandomCommand($length = 10): string {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x=implode('',RoverConstants::AVAILABLE_COMMANDS), ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}

$factory->define(Grid::class,function(Faker $faker){
    return [
        'width'=>rand(1,10),
        'height'=>rand(1,10)
    ];
});

$factory->define(Rover::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    $command = generateRandomCommand(rand(0));
    $commandLength = strlen($command);
    $commandPos = rand(0,$commandLength);
    $lastExecutedCommand = substr($command,$commandPos,$commandPos);

    $randomGrid=Grid::inRandomOrder();

    return [
        'grid_id' => $randomGrid->value('id'),
        'grid_pos_x' => rand(0,$randomGrid->value('width')),
        'grid_pos_y' => rand(0,$randomGrid->value('height')),
        'rotation' => RoverConstants::ORIENTATION_EAST,
        'command' => $command,
        'last_commandPos' => $commandPos,
        'last_command' => $lastExecutedCommand,
    ];
});
```

But how I can ensure that the `$randomGrid=Grid::inRandomOrder();` will always return a Grid? I other words I want to check is there's no grid then call the `Grid` Factory to make one from the `Rover` Factory.

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I suggest you always make a new grid. If you want to use an existing grid do that when you are generating `Rover` but not in the factory e.g. `factory(Rover::class)->make([ 'grid_id' => x])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer not sufficient, just here for reference!**

If you want to be sure there is always a grid there, you can create one (call the GridFactory) at that place. If you want to use an existing grid, you can override this attribute. Like so:

```
$factory->define(Rover::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    $command = generateRandomCommand(rand(0));
    $commandLength = strlen($command);
    $commandPos = rand(0,$commandLength);
    $lastExecutedCommand = substr($command,$commandPos,$commandPos);

    //This will create a second entry in the database.
    $randomGrid = factory(Grid::class)->create();

    return [
        'grid_id' => $randomGrid->id, //no need for the value() method, they are all attributes
        'grid_pos_x' => rand(0,$randomGrid->width), 
        'grid_pos_y' => rand(0,$randomGrid->height),
        'rotation' => RoverConstants::ORIENTATION_EAST,
        'command' => $command,
        'last_commandPos' => $commandPos,
        'last_command' => $lastExecutedCommand,
    ];
});
```

Above factory shows a grid being created on the fly whenever the RoverFactory is called. Creating a new rover with `factory(Rover::class)->create()` will also create a new Grid (and save it). Now if you want to use an existing grid, you can do the following:

```
factory(Rover::class)->create([
    'grid_id' => $existingGrid->id,
    'grid_pos_x' => rand(0, $existingGrid->width),
    'grid_pos_y' => rand(0, $existingGrid->height),
]);
```

This will create a Rover with an existing grid (which you might have created before with the GridFactory or something. Hope this works for you. Enjoy Laravel!

**Edit:**

Normally you would do something like this:

```
$factory->define(Rover::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    $command = generateRandomCommand(rand(0));
    $commandLength = strlen($command);
    $commandPos = rand(0,$commandLength);
    $lastExecutedCommand = substr($command,$commandPos,$commandPos);

    return [
        'grid_id' => function() {
            return factory(Grid::class)->create()->id;
        }
        'grid_pos_x' => '', //But then i got nothing for this.
        'grid_pos_y' => '', //But then i also got nothing for this.
        'rotation' => RoverConstants::ORIENTATION_EAST,
        'command' => $command,
        'last_commandPos' => $commandPos,
        'last_command' => $lastExecutedCommand,
    ];
});
```

Comment: But in this approach won't I have 2 Grids in my database? In this case how I can 'disable' the creation of a grid in a factory? Can I pass ectra flags and parasmeters into the factory?

Comment: You are right. I will edit my answer. I can not think of a proper solution for your problem at the moment. Excuse me. You may want to decline my answer as it does not solve your problem sufficiently. I don't have any knowledge of passing extra parameters and or flags to the factories other than overriding the amount to create and the attributes to override. Maybe checkout the Laravel documentation.

Comment: Also you can pass a callback function that returns the `grid_id` as seen in [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56749976/4706711). So in case of an ovveride it won't be called.

Comment: That is what i added in my edited part of my answer. There i used the correct way of passing a callback function. But then i dont know how you would pass the `grid_pos_x` and `grid_pos_y` variables.

Comment: What if I let the closure access some variables outside closure's scope in order to temrporary store the generated grid?

Comment: Als as you can see I can also use closures and search for the grid tha thas  `grid_id`. As you see in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#using-factories you can access the model's attributed via the array `$rover`.