# I want to make a secure link

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, random

i want to make a code generator link,like

`www.website.com/register?code=29U3HTR3H219URH923UH419H94RH1298491U2HERUH1?plan_bought=LowReseller`

in a functions file on php that is redirecting an user on that link.

```
$planned = htmlspecialchars($_GET["planbought"]);
// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysqli_select_db($db,"ronp");


function generateRandomString($length = 16)
{
    $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, $length)), 0, $length);
}

$code_secure = generateRandomString(17);  // OR: generateRandomString(24)

$query = "INSERT INTO codes (code, expired, 'date', plan) 
                      VALUES('$code_secure', '0', date, '$planned')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);

header('Location: register?code=', $code_secure);
?>
```

Process: After payment,paypal will redirect user on https://website.com/functions_generate-ak9esysgenthos.php?planbought=Low

That link will create a code in database,and will redirect user on https://website.com/register?code_secure=(code)

Now the problem is,i get redirected on "https://website.com/register?code=",not "https://website.com/register?code=(the code created in database,like 'J2498JT9UJ249UTJ293UJ59U123J9RU9U')"

Comment: *"I want to make a secure link"* Don't go even live this code then as (blind) SQL injection is a thing in INSERT also

Comment: I dont know what url you are exactly passing to paypal but in the url above you are using `?` as a seperator for your query params but it has to be `&` like `?foo=bar&bar=foo`

Comment: I will make a system to stop sql injection.

Comment: I use just one URL parameter,so,i don't need to use '&'.

Comment: *"I will make a system to stop sql injection"*  System to stop SQL injections? What do you mean?  I hope you simply meant i will use prepared statements with that comment..

Comment: One parameter = blahblah.com/test?variable=value

2 parameters = blahblah.com/test?variable=value&variable2=value2

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) you'll see that the second parameter is a boolean value. This parameter specifies if the header should be "forcefully" be replaced. You are incorrectly passing your "secure"* code as that parameter.

What you want to do is [concatenate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the strings instead of passing your "secure" code as a second parameter. What you want to get is

```
header('Location: register?code=' . $code_secure);
```

---

*The "secure" code you are generating is predictable (as you used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13212994/5914775)), if you need a secure code you might want to look into [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) before PHP 7.0 and [`random_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) in PHP 7.0 or higher, as demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672573/5914775).

Furthermore, as mentioned by [Raymond Nijland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548147/raymond-nijland) your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/5914775) on how you can prevent SQL injections.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I meant to copy the link to the answer below that, which correctly uses `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`/`random_bytes()`. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Well PHP 7 has `random_int()`  and `random_bytes()` which also are cryptographically secure indeed..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I already updated my answer to include those :)

Comment: Same problem,i enter on "https://imgur.com/fm66rY4" (that will be used by paypal on finish of transaction)

Comment: @TopKenzo I'd recommend you remove the credentials from your last comment. Regarding your previous comments, can you enable error reporting and make sure that nothing bad happens before you set the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issues mentioned in Tom Udding's answer, there are at least two other issues:

- `functions_generate-ak9esysgenthos.php` can be accessed without any authentication at all. Moreover, it generates a "secure code" blindly, without determining whether a user is logged in or otherwise authorized to access that page (e.g., without determining whether a payment operation is in progress). This could allow anyone with knowledge of the URL to access `functions_generate-ak9esysgenthos.php`; depending on how your application is implemented, this could cause orders that weren't paid for or even a denial of service attack (due to the additional order codes clogging your database).
- You are generating a random "secure code" without checking whether that code was already used. What if `/register?code=...` finds two records with the same code? Can your application tolerate the risk of generating the same code for different records? (See also my [section on unique random identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers).)

Comment: I want to redirect to register page,you don't need to login,it will generate a code,after will let you to register