# String being truncated when longer than 63 chars

Tags: php

Got a strange one here.

I'm using a function to generate a random string of chars for a token :

```
private static function generatePasswordResetCode()
{
   $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-';
   return substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH);
}
```

`RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH` is a constant :

```
define("RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH", 100);
```

The code is saved to the table like so :

```
$code = self::generatePasswordResetCode();

$expiry_timestamp = time() + RESET_CODE_EXPIRY_TIME;

$sql = "INSERT INTO reset_codes (code, user_id, expires_at)
        VALUES (:code, :user_id, :expires_at)";

$db = static::getDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':expires_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $expiry_timestamp), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

In the database the `code` column is set to `varchar(255)`. I've also tried `text` and I have the same problem either way.

Whatever I define `RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH` to be up to and including 63 chars everything works fine, but any number above that and the string is being truncated in the `code` column :

```
define("RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH", 63);

// results in
MFYflHL6bVwNEG1DpqRA0ry5TgC9KhmntPUao2x-ujvekX7sZcQizWSd43OBIJ8
```

Great, but...

```
define("RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH", 64);

// results in
7fITjSp32gmA0YJCwFhrWvPk4VDQMZonl19btBKs5Ri-zULeXO...
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

**** UPDATE ****

So this doesn't appear to be MySQL related but PHP related instead.

It seems that the combination of `substr` & `str_shuffle` result in a limit of 63 chars no matter what number above 63 you define.

To test it I changed the function like so :

```
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-';
$code = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH);
$code2 = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH);

$code = $code . $code2;
return $code;
```

Which results in the correct `var_dump` output :

```
define("RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH", 50);

//results in
string(100) "fk8DcbusUeVxWOdp1HwNLEy9gzYm6tq0o3PMaZAIh2Sn45F-K7GH9l18hZNk73j6cQpFDfPwxMCe4BTrqiIASdRs5WEnoKgmzyXY"
```

Where as doing :

```
define("RESET_TOKEN_LENGTH", 64);

//results in
string(126) "Q14Hd0WJjVotYRfsaU5pAM7DeZSuvwnCmxqbPgh6839XrEIyBcKTONzG-kil2FL0LUgQG8452WqKEfdmuzHlr9PZevc7VhnNCSjbk-wTyMR1iOspxaXYJDoFtBIA36"
```

Showing that `$code` and `$code2` are being truncated to 63 chars.

How very strange!

** UPDATE 2 **

It seems my lack of understanding as to how `str_shuffle` works was at fault here and nothing else. See the accepted answer below.

Comment: set `blob` it will work

Comment: How it the token output as it looks like how it is displayed having a limit (hence the addition of the `...`)

Comment: @dean Why won't `varchar(255)` hold 64 characters?

Comment: What database collation do you use when create this database? It seems for me you use kind of `unicode` which take 4 bytes for character

Comment: `var_dump` returns `string(63)` when 64 is defined.

Comment: collation is `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: I'm not using Drupal but this seems like it may be relevant - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/998898

Comment: By definition UTF-8 take from 1 to 4 bytes. And maybe this is the reason. Try to redefine column as `varchar(1024)`. And check the actual length of this column in database

Comment: The issue seems to be with PHP and not MySQL. As the `var_dump` shows. Anything above the defined length of 63 returns `string(63)`. Could this be something to do with `substr` or `str_shuffle`? Do they have limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the DB, nor PDO. Your `$chars` is 63 characters long and `str_shuffle` just shuffles the characters in the string around. You can't get larger than 63 characters with a 63 character string.

You might be better of looking at [PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator) to resolve your issue.

Comment: Over the 20+ years of programming PHP I've never run into this before. Was never aware that `str_shuffle` was limited to the number of chars you feed into it. I think I always just assumed that it would shuffle whatever you threw at it. You live 'n' learn! Thanks mate ;)