# Upload multiple file with ajax and laravel not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, form-data

i have some problem with my code. The problem is when i upload multiple file with Jquery Ajax(Front) and Laravel(Back) its only uploaded one file not all files.

> index.blade.php (form)

```
                <input type="file" name="file[]" class="form-control-file file-1">
                <input type="file" name="file[]" class="form-control-file file-2">
```

> index.blade.php (Ajax Jquery)

```
  var data = new FormData();

  data.append('file[0]', $('.file-1')[0].files[0]);
  data.append('file[1]', $('.file-2')[0].files[0]);

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '{{ url('/layanan/file/users/store') }}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response){
      mprogress.end();
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
```

> php file logic @store

```
    $request->file[0]->move(public_path('file'), time().'.'.$request->file[0]->extension());
    $request->file[1]->move(public_path('file'), time().'.'.$request->file[1]->extension());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use `time()` to generate random file name on both cases. Since each line is likely to take less than a second, `time()` will return the same value for both, meaning that file#2 will have the same name as file#1 and will override it.

Try using different file name generation, maybe just static names like `file1` and `file2` instead of `time()`, or generate random file names with one of the techniques mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator).