# PHP Replace specific characters in string with random charcters without foreach loop

Tags: php

I have string $template= "KEK-####" 
I need to replace all '#' symbols with random int and return modified string 
I tried this:

```
$result = '';

foreach (str_split($template) as $templateChar){
  if ($templateChar === '#'){
    $templateChar = random_int(1, 9);
  }
  $result .= $templateChar;
}
return $result;
```

And it works but it fails when there's a lot of new strings to generate (too many foreach loops with if else condition in them)

`$template = str_replace('#', random_int(1,9), $string);` doesn't work for me because it will return "KEK-888888" and I need my new strings to be unique
Is there a way to get rid of this foreach loop or make it faster?

Comment: You can use `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: As for the second part of your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator